# In MATE desktop, Right click context menu not as desired

Tags: desktop-environment, mate-desktop

I want to right click on a folder and easily open it in my favorite music player, say VLC. I have chosen "Other Application" and selected VLC and the option to "Remember" this selection. The folder then opens in VLC exactly as I would expect. But the option never sticks. It's just as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is such a 'remember' setting available in Properties? If so, can you try it?

Comment: Yes, that is why I stated that I used the "Remember" checkbox.

Comment: Ok, that was not clear to me. Why would you write it like that then, as if choosing "Other Application" was at related to "Remember" option?